# Word for "number of times a value is copied"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for "the number of times a value is copied".

**Context**:

My company makes software for plant breeders. Breeders do observations on plants and when they create a new generation of plants, e.g. by crossings, they copy observation values to this new generation. Of course, when this is done several times, the values become less reliable because of genetic changes. So we want to show a table with values and a column with this "number of times a value is copied" (to a new generation) as a short header.

Comment: This sounds very specific to their business domain, and rather technical, so I'd suggest asking the client what *they* want to see.

Comment: Good idea, but the majority of them are no native speakers (like myself) and we have many clients with just as many opinions. We like to be in charge ourselves.

Comment: *Copy generation*?

Comment: Yes, but "generation" would suggest a connection with the genetic generation, which is not always the case. I'm looking for a "dry" word without any connotations in genetics. It might as well apply to archiving, for instance.

Comment: @GertArnold, well however the *copy generation* from your example is actually related to *genetic generation* (it is not equal, but it is related; the adjective *copy* should make enough distinction imo). Also, why not "times copied"?

Comment: @Unreason: the relationship is not straightforward, but explaining that is a bit off-topic. I like the simple "times copied" though.

Comment: I don't think "generation" necessarily implies anything genetic. Before digital storage became widespread for audio/video, [second generation tape](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22second%20generation%20tape%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en), for example, was widely used to mean a tape copy made from a tape original (with consequent loss of quality always understood).

Comment: Agree, we sometimes try to make "next generation" software that has nothing to do with plants whatsoever.

Comment: Which also shows that higher *generations* don't necessarily have inherent positive/negative connotations, in that *second generation software* is generally expected to be "better", unlike *second generation tapes*.

Comment: There are two concepts here and you only mean one of them.  A word like "count" would include branches -- you copied this to A, B, and C, and from A to D and B to E etc; there are five or more copies but the *depth* is only two (for D and E).  If you mean "number of copies removed from the source", that's a word like "generation" or perhaps "depth" (as suggested by FWFD).

Comment: @MonicaCellio: in this context _depth_ would be better because plant breeders would be side-tracked by the word generation. Branches are not involved, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe *propagation depth*, in reference to how many generations a trait gets [propagated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propagate).

---

Other terms that might sound less biology-related could be *copy count*, *value copy count*, *iterations*.

Comment: Thanks, but see my comment above which came just a minute late.

Comment: @GertArnold: Ok, give me a few minutes to come up with a term that sounds less related to biology. ;)

Comment: Thanks, one of these will certainly do! In software it is always very important to use words that do not suggest anything else. (Like a forms designer that also messes up forms).

Comment: Replications...

Answer (score 5):

You might consider using *multiplicity*. In mathematics this refers to the number of times the same root of an equation or zero of a function occurs.

Comment: I must say I like this term. It is probably the canonical word. But it lacks the connotation of a time sequence that I would like to see in our context.

Answer (score 2):

**Value repetition** could convey the meaning you want.

Comment: Hmmm, sounds good...

Comment: I assume OP is interested in the *number of generations* from the original, since it makes no difference how many "siblings" are created within each generation. To me, *value repetition* implies the total of all copies, rather than "propagation depth".

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a title like *data age* or *data vintage*.  The latter usage would be analogous to *[vintage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vintage)* denoting the "year and vineyard or district of origin" of a wine.

Incidentally, it probably is inappropriate to say that "the values become less reliable because of genetic changes".  The data does not become less *reliable*, it becomes less *applicable* to current generations.

*Update*: Phrase *copy count* is short and to the point.  Also *replications*.

Comment: Yes, there you are right. The words "age" and "vintage" are less applicable though, because crops vary vastly in the time it takes to get a new generation. The "number" would be related to a few months in one crop and five years in an other one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with *preservation times*, *maintenance times*, and *persistence times* for discussion.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Darwin Factor"?

Perhaps I misinterpret what it is showing, but is it demonstrating how well a genetic trait survives pressures of environment and therefore survival of the fittest from one generation to the next? i.e. the more generations a value is copied down, the "fitter" that genetic trait is?

Comment: This would tell something about the quality of the value, but the _copy count_ (or _copy depth_) has no qualification in it. It only indicates that a value may need verification.